# Name for integrals where the integral is divided by the range of integration?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definition, stochastic-calculus

I've seen this sort of integral come up when I've been studying approximating step processes to some very simple stochastic processes, but I can't shake the feeling that they link to some more general (and possibly, statistical or analytical?) idea that I am failing to recall the name of.

What is the name, if any, for integrals of the form $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{dx}$? Is there any such name for the integrals of step functions? For example, $\frac{1}{x_1-x_0}\int_{x_0}^{x_1} c_1 \ \mathrm{dx}$?

Comment: It is the *mean value* of the function on the interval

Comment: @Bernard I suspected as much, and indeed, it does remind me of the uniform distribution. However, I can't see the classic 'xf(x)' part anywhere. Am I thinking too Riemann?

Comment: I don't see what $xf(x)$ refers to?

Comment: You're confusing "the mean value of a random variable with distribution given by $f(x)$" with the mean value of the function, ala [the mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals). For comparison, if you wanted the average of three past dice rolls, you would add the values up and divide by 3, not have terms like "5*(1/6)"(as in a calculation of the mean value of a potential dice roll).

Comment: @MarkS. Spot on. Repost and reformat that as an answer and this question will be done. I knew that I was being stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we wish to take the ([arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean)) mean of finitely values, we add them up and divide by the number of values. Analogously, we traditionally define the *mean* of a function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ to be given by an expression like the one in the question: $\dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$. This terminology comes up in the name of [the mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals).

As an aside, do not confuse with the calculation of [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) ("mean") given a discrete or continuous probability distribution. That sort of calculation is more like "the mean of all possible rolls of a die, weighted by probability" than "the mean of these particular rolls of a die that happened".

Comment: One might even say that the expression $f(x)$, rewritten as $x^0 f(x)$, when integrated and divided by the size of the domain, gives us the "0th moment" of $f$, while $xf(x)$, integrated, etc., gives us the first moment, etc. Other "moments" arise often, although these two are the most common.